# Problem with receiving correct integer from c# inteface

Tags: c#, pic, uart, mikroc

I am programming a dynamic C# interface to show real time states of my line follower robot sensors and motors. I am also sending a threshold of sensors to a microcontroller.

My code is:

```
char uart_rd[10];
unsigned long v;

while (UART1_Data_Ready() == 1) {
  UART1_Read_Text(uart_rd, "\0", 255);
  delay_ms(1000);

  v = uart_rd;
  UART1_Write_Text(v);

  PORTD = v;
}
```

My C# Code to send the number is :

```
private void sendData()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("sending");
            string Seuil = SeuilVal.Text;
            ComPort.Write(Seuil);           // Send the user's text straight out the port
            Console.WriteLine(Seuil);
            //SeuilVal.Clear();                       //clear screen after sending data
        }
```

Now I want to receive the threshold value with MikroC. 
When I send a number with 2 digits (99 for example) things are fine but when I send a number with 3 digits or more, I just receive two first digits (example I send 1234, but I receive 12).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty shocked that what you're describing even close to works. The line `v = uart_rd;` is assigning the POINTER of char array to the `v` variable, and `UART1_Write_Text` takes a  `char *` as an input, not a `ulong`.

What you probably want to do is parse the string received to a long. You can do this with `atol` which comes in the `stdlib` library from mikroC. However, if you want to echo back what you've received on UART, just do `UART1_Write_Text(uart_rd);` as it already has the data encoded as a string.